# why IOS13 Login with facebook does not work?

Tags: swift, facebook, authentication

I click the Facebook button but it is unresponsive on iOS 13, but on iOS 12.x it works fine. What should I do?

I am using: 
1) pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.13.1' 
2) pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.13.1' 
 
3) pod 'FacebookCore' 
4) pod 'FacebookLogin' 
5) pod 'FacebookShare'

Comment: i am using 
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.13.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.13.1'
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'

Comment: Please add some code. Also, have you tested on an actual device?

Comment: @emredoğmaz please see my answer.

Comment: You will definitely have an issue trying to use a combination of 'FBSDK' prefixed pods with the deprecated 'Facebook' prefixed pods. See: https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-swift-sdk/blob/master/MigrationGuide.md

Answer (score 12):

Your appdelegate in open url method not working because ios13 in change

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
  return 
}
```

you have to latest xcode in work than SceneDelegate.swift file in add this method. please try it.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
      guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
          return
      }
      let _ = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
          UIApplication.shared,
          open: url,
          sourceApplication: nil,
          annotation: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
  }
```

and not forgot to import **FBSDKLoginKit** in SceneDelegate

Comment: @balkaran singh thanks for edit and upvote my answer.

Comment: @HardikThakkar wlc bro

Comment: I love you... just know that!

Answer (score -2):

set info.plist url types 
[image]

```
//create a function for present root view controller in AppDelegate create var window: UIWindow? 

var appDelegateShared: AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate ?? AppDelegate()
}

create a class for Facebook login
    class WFacebookManager: NSObject {
        typealias FBCallback = (Bool, Any?) -> Void
        var handler: FBCallback?
        static let shared: WFacebookManager = WFacebookManager()
        public func loginWithFacebook(completion: @escaping FBCallback ) {
            handler = completion
            let fbLoginManager: LoginManager = LoginManager()
            fbLoginManager.logOut()
            let presentView = appDelegateShared.window?.rootViewController!
            fbLoginManager.logIn(permissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: presentView) { (result, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if (result?.isCancelled)! {
                        self.handler?(false, nil)
                        return
                    } else if AccessToken.current != nil {
                        let values = "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"
                        let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": values])
                        request.start(completionHandler: { (_, result, error) in
                            self.handler?(error == nil, result)
                        })
                    }
                } else {
                    self.handler?(false, nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // on your action call function then get login data
    @IBAction func loginWithFacebook(_ sender: Any) {
            WFacebookManager.shared.loginWithFacebook { (success, data) in
                if let data = data as? [String: Any], success {
                    print (data)
                }
            }
        }
```