# Facebook Login in Firebase (iOS), Error 10814

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, facebook, oauth

I am getting the following error when trying to log in using Facebook and Firebase in iOS (swift):

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

I get the error in my console as soon as I click my "login with facebook" UIButton - right when it says "APPNAME wants to use facebook.com to Sign In". None of the print statements in my loginButton function (in AppDelegate.swift) are executed, and neither is the print statement in onContinueFacebookButton. My app has google and facebook login but the facebook login does not work and I don't get why. After the Facebook login it is supposed to switch to the main view controller but it does not do that, even though the switch to the main view controller works for the Google sign in.

I am testing on a Facebook account with no Multi-factor authentication enabled.

I have seen a few posts on this topic, and I have tried almost every solution I can find. Some people are saying it is just a meaningless error and can be ignored, but my app isn't working and I'm pretty sure this is why. Here are some of my attempts so I don't get downvoted to oblivion:

1. Adding entries to the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist:

- fbapi
- fbapi20130214
- fbapi20130410
- fbapi20130702
- fbapi20131010
- fbapi20131219
- fbapi20140410
- fbapi20140116
- fbapi20150313
- fbapi20150629
- fbapi20160328
- fbauth
- fb-messenger-share-api
- fbauth2
- fbshareextension

2. Adding FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKShareKit to my Podfile and also importing it in the swift files.
3. Modifying functions in various ways. This is my current setup (my app allows for Google and Facebook login right now).

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate, LoginButtonDelegate {
\\...
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // ...
        
        FirebaseApp.configure();
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        // ...
}

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Facebook login: Immediate error. Aborting...")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                let authError = error as NSError
                if (authError.code == AuthErrorCode.secondFactorRequired.rawValue) {
                    // The user is a multi-factor user. Second factor challenge is required.
                    print("FB Login: Aborting due to MFS error")
                    let resolver = authError.userInfo[AuthErrorUserInfoMultiFactorResolverKey] as! MultiFactorResolver
                    var displayNameString = ""
                    for tmpFactorInfo in (resolver.hints) {
                        displayNameString += tmpFactorInfo.displayName ?? ""
                        displayNameString += " "
                    }
                } else {
                    print("FB Login: Aborting to error")
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                return
            }
            // Switch to main page after sign-in
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabViewController")
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        }
        
    }

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
    print("Logged out of Facebook")
}

// Used for both Google and FB sign in
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
      -> Bool {
        let handled =  ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
        annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
      return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url) || handled
    }
}
```

In my LoginViewController.swift:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
\\ ...
    @IBOutlet weak var continueGoogleButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var continueFacebookButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
\\...
        
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
}

// Linked to "login with google" button
@IBAction func onContinueGoogleButton(_ sender: Any) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}

// Linked to "login with facebook" button
   @IBAction func onContinueFacebookButton(_ sender: Any) {
        LoginManager().logIn(permissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self) { (result, err) in
            if (err != nil){
                print("FB Login Failed")
                return
            }
            //print(result?.token.tokenString)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please see my answer :-https://stackoverflow.com/a/59606803/6920041

Answer (score 0):

I've used only the 'FacebookLogin' pod

Added the following in plist as you mentioned

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbapi20160328</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Create FacebookLogin.swift file to manage the common functions

```
    import UIKit
    import FBSDKLoginKit
    class FacebookSignInManager: NSObject {
    typealias LoginCompletionBlock = (Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?, NSError?) -> Void
    
    //MARK:- Public functions
    class func basicInfoWithCompletionHandler(_ fromViewController:AnyObject, onCompletion: @escaping LoginCompletionBlock) -> Void {
        //Check internet connection if no internet connection then return
        self.getBaicInfoWithCompletionHandler(fromViewController) { (dataDictionary:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            onCompletion(dataDictionary, error)
        }
    }
    
    class func logoutFromFacebook() {
        LoginManager().logOut()
        AccessToken.current = nil
        Profile.current = nil
    }
    
    //MARK:- Private functions
    class fileprivate func getBaicInfoWithCompletionHandler(_ fromViewController:AnyObject, onCompletion: @escaping LoginCompletionBlock) -> Void {
        let permissionDictionary = [
            "fields" : "id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,email,birthday,picture.type(large)",
            //"locale" : "en_US"
        ]
        if AccessToken.current != nil {
            GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: permissionDictionary)
                .start(completionHandler:  { (connection, result, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        onCompletion(result as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, nil)
                    } else {
                        onCompletion(nil, error as NSError?)
                    }
                })
        
        } else {
            LoginManager().logIn(permissions: ["email", "public_profile", "user_photos"], from: fromViewController as? UIViewController, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    LoginManager().logOut()
                    if let error = error as NSError? {
                        let errorDetails = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Processing Error. Please try again!"]
                        let customError = NSError(domain: "Error!", code: error.code, userInfo: errorDetails)
                        onCompletion(nil, customError)
                    } else {
                        onCompletion(nil, error as NSError?)
                    }
                    
                } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
                    LoginManager().logOut()
                    let errorDetails = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Request cancelled!"]
                    let customError = NSError(domain: "Request cancelled!", code: 1001, userInfo: errorDetails)
                    onCompletion(nil, customError)
                } else {
                    let pictureRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: permissionDictionary)
                    let _ = pictureRequest.start(completionHandler: {
                        (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                        
                        if error == nil {
                            onCompletion(result as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, nil)
                        } else {
                            onCompletion(nil, error as NSError?)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

On Facebook button tap: do the following

```
    // Linked to "login with facebook" button
   @IBAction func onContinueFacebookButton(_ sender: Any) {
       FacebookSignInManager.logoutFromFacebook()
        FacebookSignInManager.basicInfoWithCompletionHandler(self) { (dataDictionary:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if let detailsDic = dataDictionary, let email = dic["email"], let firstName = dic["first_name"], let lastName = dic["last_name"], let socialId = dic["id"]{
                print(detailsDic)
            }
        }
    }
```